# Difficulty activating discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

Im a big newbie with all things coding. But im trying to learn how to make discord bots myself, but i ran into an issue trying to get discord.py rewrite working. Im trying to follow a tutorial on the subject, but were everyone else gets through without issues i cant progress. Im using the code `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite` but everytime i have tried it comes back with this.

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q rewrite Check the logs for full command output.

Can anyone help with this? Also, im using Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rewrite branch anymore.  That branch has been released, so you can just

```
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```